# Disable fluentd on on Container-Optimized OS (GCE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, fluentd

I would like to disable `fluentd` on a VM instance running Container-Optimized OS on Google compute engine.

The reason being that it is eating up a lot of RAM for functionalities I do not require.

```sh
$ ps aux --sort -rss
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root        1040  0.7 49.1 5149544 294484 ?      Sl   15:07   0:03 /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/ruby -Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit /usr/sbin/google-fluentd --under-supervisor
root         286  0.2 12.3 780428 73844 ?        Ssl  15:07   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd --registry-mirror=https://mirror.gcr.io --host=fd:// --containerd=/var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root         791  0.4  9.0 304208 54068 ?        Ssl  15:07   0:01 /opt/google-fluentd/embedded/bin/ruby /usr/sbin/google-fluentd
root         334  0.0  7.3 609056 44100 ?        Ssl  15:07   0:00 /usr/bin/docker run --rm --name=stackdriver-logging-agent -v /etc/stackdriver/logging.config.d/:/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/ -v /var/log:/var/log 
root         333  0.0  7.3 535324 43820 ?        Ssl  15:07   0:00 /usr/bin/docker events
```

The process is linked to this `systemd` service.

```sh
$ systemctl status stackdriver-logging.service
● stackdriver-logging.service - Fluentd container for Stackdriver Logging
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/stackdriver-logging.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-08-26 12:27:03 UTC; 1min 6s ago
  Process: 335 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/google-fluentd/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 337 (docker)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 664)
   Memory: 35.6M
      CPU: 81ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/stackdriver-logging.service
           └─337 /usr/bin/docker run --rm --name=stackdriver-logging-agent -v /etc/stackdriver/logging.config.d/:/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/ -v /var/log:/var/log -v /var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/ gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:0.2-1.5.33-1-1
```

However if I try to disable it using:

```sh
$ sudo systemctl disable --now stackdriver-logging.service
```

The disabling doesn't survive a restart of the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the the Custom metadata values. You should have two of them set as true (google-logging-enabled and google-monitoring-enabled). Set them to false and look into the instance to check if the other containers (Stackdriver related) are not running.

Comment: When I do that i switches back to true when I click on "Save" for `google-logging-enabled`.

Comment: It seems that it is impossible to set `google-logging-enabled` to false.

Comment: This is weird because I tried right now and I did successfully change the value to false. I also did it with the instance running...Try to stop the instance and then change the matadata values. Also, taking into account that your application is deployed through an image, you can create a new instance and disable logging and monitoring from the beginning.

Comment: It might have to do with my Container-Optimized OS version. I am running 78 when the default is 76 right now. It might also have to do with the region. But I have tried everything and I can't get `google-logging-enabled` to `false` with my current VM.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud CLI (Google Cloud SDK 283.0.0) worked for me:

`gcloud compute instances add-metadata <instance_name> --metadata="google-logging-enabled=false"`

Answer (score 1):

**Just delete metadata responsible for starting the logging service from the instance using console interface**

[image]

or [remove it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/remove-metadata) using `gcloud compute instances remove-metadata cont3 --zone=europe-west3-c --keys=google-logging-enabled`

**I've tested this on a fresh VM witn `ContainterOS 77` and didn't select "logging" when creating it. When I checked the service status with `systemctl status stackdriver-logging.service` it wasn't running**.

Then I created another one with logging enabled and check service status - it was running as expected. Then I stopped the instance, removed the key, started instance and checked service status. It wasn't running (also as expeceted).

If for some reason you can't remove the key from metadata you can always try [adding a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) `sudo systemctl disable --now stackdriver-logging.service`.