# GCE stackdriver logging agent (fluentd) memory leak with COS

Tags: google-compute-engine, memory-leak, google-stackdriver, fluentd

I have a VM on GCE where I run a custom Docker image. I installed it on COS (cos-stable-74-11895-125-0) to a g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory) instance.

It is an Elasticsearch with locked memory settings. It consumes exactly 1 GB of RAM.

The setup worked perfectly for nearly one year, but suddenly it stopped working as it runs out of memory.

On the serial console, it logs that the oom-killer was invoked and it selected the java process to be killed. After a quick restart, it works perfectly, but after about a day or two, it fails with the same out of memory error.

It turned out, that GCE installs and runs a Stackdriver Logging Agent in parallel with my container. According to the oom-killer log, a related *ruby* process consumes a bunch of RAM. After a reboot, it uses 50 MB of RAM and it stacks up to 300MB in a few hours. From my point of view, it seems to be a memory leak.

To make it clear: The ES server is not receiving any load, just a periodic uptime check is making requests about every 5 minutes. As a result, there are no vast amounts of logs, only a few lines per hour. A whole year of logs would not take up 300MB of storage or memory.

I tried to examine the memory footprint using the *ps* and *top* commands but the results were totally implausible. According to the system, the *ruby* task consumes 1-10GB of physical memory (RSS) and up to 70GB of virtual memory (VSZ). (Memory swapping is disabled according to the *free* command.) These figures can't be true as the VM does not have these amounts of RAM.

I tried to update the OS to a more recent version (cos-81-12871-119-0). It definitely helped as the ES was running for more than 5 days now, without a problem. But the *ruby* process's memory consumption is worrying. According to the *ps* and *top* commands, it uses 70-300MB of physical memory (RSS) and up to 7GB of virtual memory (VSZ).

I found that the *ruby* process is part of the *fluentd* tool which had a similar memory problem according to their GitHub. As the configuration and installation are automatically done by GCE I did not found a way to change its settings.

The easiest solution would be to disable the installation of the logging agent by changing the VM metadata. (google-logging-enabled=false). But I would like to find out the reason why this happens and how can I solve it.

I'm really curious if anybody had a similar problem, and what was the solution.

Stackdriver Logging Agent Docker image: gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:0.2-1.5.33-1-1

The error can be reproduced. I have a development and a production environment in separate GCP projects. The error appeared on both, roughly at the same time. (~2020. May. 28.) According to this, I think this is caused by a change in Stackdriver but I did not found any evidence in the logs. (Both VM instances are in eu-west3 region, in c zone.)

I would appreciate any help or advice. Thanks!

Comment: I dont have any solution, but I want to say: I am having this problem! 

Thank you for writing it up. I have a very similar situation with a small GCE node, and I was surprised to see a Ruby process getting killed in the logs. Despite never installing Ruby (which I detest for this reason among others).

Comment: Please advocate for the newer OpsAgent to support Container OS at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/issues/325

Comment: My solution was to upgrade the instance type to have more memory that also benefited to the elastic search. I have not experienced any issues since then except for the higher cost.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing similar problems:

**cos-77-12371-1109-0** running on **g1-small** uses memory as follows:

```
MiB Mem :   1692.4 total,   1409.3 free,    176.0 used,    107.1 buff/cache
```

[Cloud Monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/installation) has it's own memory requirements:

> A minimum of 250 MiB of resident (RSS) memory is recommended to run the Monitoring agent.

On top of that, there's docker:

> It is an Elasticsearch with locked memory settings. It consumes exactly 1 GB of RAM.

So 1409-1000-250=159 MB left, which is less than 10% margin.

To avoid out-of-memory issues, consider [disabling fluentd](https://serverfault.com/questions/980569/disable-fluentd-on-on-container-optimized-os-gce/1030981#1030981) or create VM with more RAM.
If you think you found a bug with GCP, you can file an issue on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).